# i try to import a array data in JS file from another js file in react native , and i try to check the length of the array in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, react-native

[image]

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_kurals.default.length')
i got this error.
[image]

```
export const kurals =[];
import kurals from './kurals';
 console.log(`data1.length`, kurals.length);
```

Comment: could you show us your code

Comment: `_kurals.default` seems to be undefined.

Comment: export const kurals =[];
import kurals from './kurals';
 console.log(`data1.length`, kurals.length);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import it as a default, like you did with `import kurals from './kurals';`, then it must be exported as default:

```js
export default [];
```

Since you exported it with `export const kurals = [];` then it's a property of the exported object and you need to destructure it:

```js
import { kurals } from './kurals';
```